# How can I unit test that something behaves differently when Python is in optimised mode?

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging

Python allows you to run a script in "optimised mode" by passing the -O option. If I save this script as "assert.py":

```
assert False
print("Hello")
```

then these two invocations of Python result in different output (one prints an exception message and stack trace, while the other says hello):

```
python -m assert
python -O -m assert
```

The author of a Python script can determine whether Python is in optimised mode by checking the value of the global name `__debug__`. This allows us to do different things depending upon whether we are running in optimised mode or not.

Suppose that I want to do one thing if Python is in optimised mode, and another quite different thing if it is not. This is easy enough - we can use `if __debug__:`. But now suppose that I want to unit test that the behaviour in each case is correct. How should I go about doing this?

It occurred to me that I could set the value of `__debug__`, but you're not allowed to do this:

```
>>> __debug__ = False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
assert 123

if __debug__:
    do_something()
```

Optimized bytecode will be empty. `assert` and bare `if __debug__` statements are evaluated during bytecode compilation, not at runtime. So, even if you succeed at changing `__debug__` (e.g. with `setattr(builtins, '__debug__', True)`), you still won't be able to execute that code.

The only way you have is to run the test suite twice, first without `-O`, then with `-O`. Obviously you can automate this part, you don't have to do it manually.

---

For completeness:

```
$ python3
>>> dis.dis('assert 123')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (123)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        12
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (AssertionError)
              9 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('if __debug__: do_something()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (do_something)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 POP_TOP
              7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
$ python3 -O
>>> dis.dis('assert 123')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('if __debug__: do_something()')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that only bare `if __debug__` statements are optimized out. If you use complex conditions, they will appear in the bytecode:

```
$ python3 -O
>>> dis.dis('if __debug__ and something_else: do_something()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__debug__)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (something_else)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (do_something)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             18 POP_TOP
             19 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 22)
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```